# pyqt declaring a QtCore.pyslot for an instance method

Tags: python, pyqt

While trying to set up a new slot and signal between a worker network `QRunnable` and code submitting it with callbacks (to handle network responses), I've got the following line of code:

```
exception_callback = QtCore.pyqtSlot('PyQt_PyObject', str)(exception_callback)
```

where `exception_callback` is a bound member function of some class instance. However, the aforementioned line fails with the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__pyqtSignature__'
```

What am I missing?

Edit:

A simple reproduction:

```
class A(QtCore.QObject):
  def a(self):
    print("Called")

a=A()
QtCore.pyqtSlot()(a.a)
```

Will raise the following exception:

```
AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__pyqtSignature__'
```

A workaround I found is that wrapping the member function and using a closure around the member function, like so, will work:

```
QtCore.pyqtSlot()(lambda : a.a())
```

However this is a little messy and I rather not use the workaround without understanding it's necessity.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc, that's for your response. addes a simple reproduction snippet

Comment: @NirIzr. Why do you feel you need to use `pyqtSlot`? It serves no purpose at all in your example.

Comment: @ekhumoro that's because the example reproduces the issue, not the use case.

Comment: @NirIzr. So what is the actual use-case? If the `QRunnable` example at the beginning of your question isn't relevant, why have you included it? All you need to do to fix the example is remove the redundant `pyqtSlot` wrapper and simply pass the callable object itself in the signal connection.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for your assistance! as far as I understand, using `pyqtSlot`s should not be an issue, so although this error may be avoided I'm still interested in using `pyqtSlot` for resilience and future proofing my code, for when it may matter. Moreover, I would like to understand the issue at hand regardless if only for improving my understanding of pyqt and skills. Thanks again!

Comment: And regarding the example at the start of my question, I initially thought   the error may be related to incorrectly defining the arguments in `pyqtSlot`. Writing a minimal example proved this isn't the case, as I was able to reproduce the error without method arguments.

Comment: Anyway, going over this again after a night sleep, spotting the mistake was easy. Sorry for triple posting and thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*leaving this here in case someone else makes the same stupid mistake and fails spotting the error, like myself*

In my reproduction example the error is quite clear and was relatively easy to spot. On line `QtCore.pyqtSlot()(a.a)` I'm mistakenly wrapping a *bound* instance method, where pyqt only allows using `pyqtSlot` at method/function *definition* time.

Simply using `QtCore.pyqtSlot()` as a decorator when defining the method is one solution, which I wanted to avoid.